# Responsive circle with images and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to build the below circle with embedded logos and text. I've been using Bootstrap for responsiveness, and this piece needs to follow suit. I'm currently running into a couple issues:

1) Text stays on 1 line and does not wrap when there are multiple sentences

2) Can't embed the necessary logos or button

Also below is the HTML & CSS

[image]

```css
    .circle {
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 50% 0;
      line-height: 0;
      position: relative;
      background: #38a9e4;
      color: white;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial Black, sans;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="circle">
      Text text text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You didn't say what you wanted to be done on smaller viewports. Here it stacks and centers since the content can't fit a circle without being very tiny and not good looking on smaller viewports.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/duveli/1/**

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: #777;
    padding: 5% 0;
}

.feature {background:pink;padding:10% 0}
.circle .btn {
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #000;
    border: #000;
}
.circle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.circle-wrapper {
    margin: 0 5%;
    position: relative;
}
.circle .list-inline {
    font-size: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
.circle .list-inline li {
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
}
.circle p {
    padding-top: 10%;
    margin: 0;
}
@media (min-width:460px) { 
    .circle .list-inline li {
        font-size: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .circle-wrapper {
        max-width: 450px;
        position: relative;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .circle {
        height: 0px;
        padding: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .circle > div {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        left: 10%;
        right: 10%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        top:20%\9; /* ie8 hack test this out it's a guess */
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<section class="feature">

<div class="circle-wrapper">
   <div class="circle text-center">
      <div>
         <ul class="list-inline">
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/OOO/FFFFFF&text=image+1" alt=""></li>
            <li class="plus">+</li>
            <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/OOO/FFFFFF&text=image+2" alt=""></li>
         </ul>
         <p>content goes herecontent goes herecontent goes herecontent goes herecontent goes herecontent goes herecontent goes herecontent goes here goes herecontent goes herecontent goes here</p>
         <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Button Goes Here</a></p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

As for your first issue, if you want each sentence on a separate line, use a line break, `<br />`.

If you just want the text to wrap, put the text inside of `<p>` tags or `<span>` tags so you can define the width. That way it will wrap when it reaches the width of the element.